# Connect Google Sheets by C # using the KEY API (not OAuth2)

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to do a search within a sheet.
I manage to get a list of entries ([https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetsID}/values/1?alt=json&key={API](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%7BspreadsheetsID%7D/values/1?alt=json&key=%7BAPI) KEY})

but am unable to perform a search.
I use API KEY Is it possible to get an example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately, there is no method in Sheets API which lets you perform a search.

This has already been reported on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198890883). I suggest you star the issue and eventually add a comment as well stating that you are interested in this feature.